# Refresh Token to access service end points

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin form, I have used google authorization for login. On login i get a access token that i send with request to web api. Time duration of token is 1 hour. I have build a functionality the refresh the token after 55 minutes. 
 But i am getting issue with refresh token when application is sleep mode for more than 1 hour, that time refresh token is not generated because refresh token is generated basis on token that is generated at login time. Please help me out, how i can fix this issue. 
Here is code of refresh token:-

```
var user = await AzureMobileService.DefaultManager.MobileService.RefreshUserAsync();
            Settings.AuthToken = user?.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `OnStart`, `OnSleep` & `OnResume` methods inside `App.cs` . When you refreshed the token , save the timestamp in somewhere, then override `OnResume` method & check if token expired. If so refresh it.

Comment: Lets suppose i'm using these override methods. I am logged in and i have access token that is valid for 1 hour. I have used application for 15 minutes and then closed the application and again logged in after 1 and half hour. Now token time has expired we can not generate refresh token with the help of that token, this thing i'm facing.